# Importing data in Bigquery using Datastore export with Schema

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore export which I want to import in Bigquery specifying a schema for the table.

When I specify the schema I receive the following error.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/easylr-184605/jobs: Datastore backup imports may not specify a schema.
```

I understand specifying a schema is not required but I want to do so nonetheless because automatic inference creates numeric columns with `RECORD` type which requires querying `integer` and `float` separately. I want to avoid that completely by changing the datatype to `float`.

Code Snippet for Importing

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.DATASTORE_BACKUP,
    write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
    schema=schema
)
job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
    source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config
)
job.result()
```

while schema is of the form

```
[
  {
    "description": "field1",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "field1",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  },
  {
    "description": "field2",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "field2",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting a schema to a Load Job from a Datastore export is not possible in `BigQuery`.
It means that the schema will always be inferred from the data. If you try to load it through the UI for example, you will see a message saying

> Source file defines the schema

In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore?&_ga=2.226933661.-1652439137.1584564182&_gac=1.162195080.1599468536.EAIaIQobChMI9fL0qdTW6wIVGpOyCh1MIAkLEAAYASAAEgK1UvD_BwE#data_type_conversion) you can find how the type conversion works between Datastore and BigQuery.
 Apparently **Floating-point number** is converted to FLOAT and **Integer** is converted to INTEGER what makes me think that maybe your Datastore fields have another type?

Nevertheless, if you want to change your schema in BigQuery I can suggest you three possible approaches:

1. Use a View as the final table
2. Create a scheduled query to read your table when its loaded and save the results in another table with the right schema.
3. If you are loading the Datastore reports manually and not constantly, just create a new table with the desired schema by querying your table with the wrong schema.

Comment: For Datastore since the type in not defined at the column level, a single column can have multiple types. In my case a column has numbers which means both integer and float in different records which get separated out when importing from datastore.

Thanks for the suggestions I did try building a View which worked well but wanted to know if there is a better way. Between #1 and #2, is there a preferred way?

Comment: @KunalJain  how frequently are you importing this data into BigQuery? You have to think the following: If you use a view, the view's query will be executed for each query you execute. This is good for real time scenarios for example. If you choose the second approach, your query will be executed directly from the table you created. If you update (load) a lot of data and dont access it so much, use a view. If you dont update (load) a lot of data but you you access it very frequently, choose the scheduled query.